# How to use CombineFn to merge windowed PCollection of KV<String, String> to List<KV<String, String>>

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a requirement to convert a windowed PCollection KV<String, String> to List<KV<String, String>> run on Google dataflow.

Basically to combine all the KV<String,String> within that 120 second window to a List<KV<String, String>>

I tried with below code and for some unknown reason the CombineFn does not seem to go anywhere and is hung.

Please let me know if the approach is correct or what am i doing wrong?

```java
public static class CombineToListFn
            extends Combine.CombineFn<KV<String, String>, List<KV<String, String>>, List<KV<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        public List<KV<String, String>> createAccumulator() {
            System.out.println("createAccumulator called");
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public List<KV<String, String>> addInput(List<KV<String, String>> accumulator, KV<String, String> input) {
            System.out.println("input: " + input);
            accumulator.add(input);
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public List<KV<String, String>> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<List<KV<String, String>>> accumulators) {
            System.out.println("mergeAccumulators called");
            List<KV<String, String>> merged = new ArrayList<>();
            for (List<KV<String, String>> accumulator : accumulators) {
                merged.addAll(accumulator);
            }
            return merged;
        }

        @Override
        public List<KV<String, String>> extractOutput(List<KV<String, String>> accumulator) {
            System.out.println("extractOutput called");
            return accumulator;
        }
    }
```

```java
PCollection<KV<String, String>> groupedData = productsAsString.apply("GroupProductData",
                Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(120))));

// Combine the groupedData into a List of KV<String, String>
PCollection<List<KV<String, String>>> combinedData = groupedData.
                apply(Combine.globally(new CombineToListFn()).withoutDefaults());
```

Comment: Are you facing any error message when running the above code?

Comment: @kiranmathew I do not see any error.. The dataflow just does not proceed any further.. I see the sysout of createAccumulator only..

Comment: You can consider using [logs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#java) in your code. By using logs you will get a better understanding about what is happening in your code.